# Synchronise Google Drive when not logged in

Tags: google-drive, synchronization, windows

I have installed Google Drive on a server. When I login to the server, Google Drive starts automatically and synchronizes files, pulling changes down from the cloud. All good so far. However, I would like the sync to run even if I am not logged in.

Is there any way to start the sync process automatically, maybe as a scheduled task?

<sub>Background: I have other jobs on the server which distribute the files by FTP so I would like the server copies of the files to be up to date.</sub>

<sub>(Windows Server 2008 R2)</sub>

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the Google Drive sync tool, not the web interface. This is more appropriate for [su].

Answer (score -2):

I found this: How to Run Google Drive 24/7 as a Windows Service with AlwaysUp
Start Google Drive Sync automatically when your computer boots. No need to log on!

Google Drive automatically synchronizes files on your Windows PC with Google's cloud storage service.

To configure Google Drive with AlwaysUp 6.0 and later:

```
Download and install AlwaysUp, if necessary.

Download, install and configure Google Drive, if necessary. Please make a note of where you installed it as this will be used in a later step.

Start AlwaysUp.

Select Application > Add to open the Add Application window:
```

Comment: Have you tried AlwaysUp with Google Driver yourself? Also, if you're affiliated with coretechnologies.com in any way, you should disclose it.